# What does it mean by 'an order of French fries'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I go McDonald and order some food:

> Casher: May I take your order?
>
> Customer: Yes. I’d like a cheeseburger,
> an order of French fries, and a large soda.

The cheeseburger and soda is not 'an order of' type. It's bit weird to say 'an order of cheeseburger' or 'an order of a large soda'. (Or do they say 'an order of a large soda'? I'm confused.)

I googled a bit and one post says 'an order of' is used for the food served with more than one chunk or uncountable food. Soda is uncountable but when it is inside a cup, it can be counted.

But what does 'an order of French fries' mean?
Does it mean a fixed amount of fries McDonald decided to serve for one order?

Then, does it make sense to ask for 'two order of French fries' if I want to eat more fries?

Comment: I get the feeling this 'order of' is an AmE usage. BrE speakers will recognise what it is, but here the request would be 'Cheeseburger, medium meal, with Coke', the 'meal' designation is "with fries & drink". Outside of such as McDonalds with their American-influenced terminology, it would be "Cheeseburger, chips & a Coke".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a fast food restaurant, french fries often are served in a small paper bag or light cardboard cup.  That's an order of fries. Two such containers of fries would constitute two orders of fries. The other two items in your example are single items, so you would not refer to either of them as an order of something, although you might refer to the entire collection of items as your order or an order.

Answer (score 1):

Language is not a matter of logic. It is mediated by social convention and common sense.

> I’d like one cheeseburger, one french fry, and one soda

Does **THAT** plausible to you?

> I’d like one cheeseburger, a number of french fries greater than one but less than 500 pounds, and one soda.

Does **THAT** sound sane to you?

What is meant is

> I’d like one cheeseburger, [the average number of] french fries [in one standard] order, and one soda.

You cannot interpret language like an ineptly programmed computer.

> Out of sight, out of mind

does not mean

> invisible idiot

Language is a human interaction.